# How to achieve display like below when @ key pressed in Edit-text field in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image]

Have created below Edittext View.

[image]

XML Code for getting the image is as follows :

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/newMessageContainer"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/curved_border"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_weight="0.85">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/newMessage"
            android:focusedByDefault="false"
            android:background="@null"
            style="@style/txt_line_2_thin_normal"
            android:hint=" @Occupation for Bulk Enquiry "
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|top"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"

        android:layout_weight="0.15">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:text="Bulk Enq"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"

            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            />

      </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

How can I achieve it? Have not created any Java code for it. Was thinking to put through popup but display of popup is not giving above view. Googled many times but not giving the right clue.

Comment: You mean, you want to display a pop up when user input an **@** symbol?

Comment: Yes I want to have display when user input @symbol. I tried to work through Popup (popup.showAsDropDown(filterText);  but not getting display as shown in Image. Dont know how to get such smooth display.